Supabase table not being updated through Sveltekit App
I've successfully fetched the information (from supabase) and it's being displayed on the page - with functionality that includes an "Edit" button.
The "Edit" button is allowing me to edit all of the list items by essentially turning the list items into input fields, and then allowing me to alter the data.
The issue is it's not actually updating the data in Supabase, and I can't seem to figure out why.
After I click "Save" - the data is visibly changed on the page, until I refresh it, and as it's not being stored in the database, the information on the page simply resets.
I've read the supabase docs, and the async function looks correct to me.
Any help would be appreciated.
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { supabase } from '../../../lib/supabaseClient';
    export let data;

    const lawfirmId = $page.params.lawfirmId;

    let editing = false;

    function editTheFirm(firm) {
        editing = !editing;
        if (!editing) {
            submitToDatabase(firm);
        }
    }
    
    async function submitToDatabase(firm) {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from('lawfirm')
                .update({
                    clientstatus: firm.clientstatus,
                    websiteurl: firm.websiteurl,
                    address1: firm.address1,
                    address2: firm.address2,
                    city: firm.city,
                    stateregion: firm.stateregion,
                    postalcode: firm.postalcode,
                    country: firm.country,
                    phonenumber: firm.phonenumber,
                    emailaddress: firm.emailaddress,
                    numberofemployees: firm.numberofemployees,
                    description: firm.description
                })
                .eq('id', lawfirmId);

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating row:', error.message);
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="lawFirmBanner">
    <h1>{decodeURIComponent(lawfirmId)}</h1>
</div>

{#each data.lawfirm as firm}
    {#if firm.lawfirmname === lawfirmId}
        <div class="lawFirmInfo">
            <ul class="lawFirmColumns">
                <li>
                    <strong>Client: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.clientstatus} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.clientstatus}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>URL: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.websiteurl} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.websiteurl}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Address 1: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.address1} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.address1}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Address 2: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.address2} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.address2}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>City: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.city} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.city}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>State: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.stateregion} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.stateregion}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Postal Code: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.postalcode} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.postalcode}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Country: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.country} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.country}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Contact: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.phonenumber} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.phonenumber}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Email: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="text" bind:value={firm.emailaddress} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.emailaddress}
                    {/if}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>Employees Count: </strong>
                    {#if editing}
                        <input type="number" bind:value={firm.numberofemployees} />
                    {:else}
                        {firm.numberofemployees}
                    {/if}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="paraLeft"><strong>Description: </strong></p>
            {#if editing}
                <textarea bind:value={firm.description}></textarea>
            {:else}
                <p>{firm.description}</p>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/each}

<div class="editButton">
    <button on:click={editTheFirm} class="editStyle">{editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}</button>
</div>


Problem resolved - the .eq needed the actual "id" - which is "lawfirmname"
async function submitToDatabase(firm) {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from('lawfirm')
                .update({
                    clientstatus: firm.clientstatus,
                    websiteurl: firm.websiteurl,
                    address1: firm.address1,
                    address2: firm.address2,
                    city: firm.city,
                    stateregion: firm.stateregion,
                    postalcode: firm.postalcode,
                    country: firm.country,
                    phonenumber: firm.phonenumber,
                    emailaddress: firm.emailaddress,
                    numberofemployees: firm.numberofemployees,
                    description: firm.description
                })
                .eq('lawfirmname', lawfirmId);




And the button on:click needed (firm) passed into the parameters.
    <button on:click={editTheFirm(firm)} class="editStyle">{editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}</button>


